# Could not get category id from database in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get category id from my database but i could not.
please help me to get category id and category image. i have also connection with my database ,
i also included this file into my this file but still i did not get category ID and category image.

```
    <?php

    $categories_query=mysql_query("select categories_id,categories_image,categories_name,categories_introduction_text  from categories where  parent_id=0");
    $no_of_row=mysql_num_rows($categories_query);
    $i=1;
    while($categories_row=mysql_fetch_array($categories_query))
    {
            $cat_id=$categories_row['categories_id'];
            $cat_image=$categories_row['categories_image'];
            $cat_name=$categories_row['categories_name'];
            $cat_into_text=$categories_row['categories_introduction_text'];
            $j=$i%2;
    }
    if($j==1)
        {
?>



<TABLE WIDTH="68%" BORDER="0" CELLPADDING="0" CELLSPACING="0" ALIGN="CENTER">
        <TR>
            <TD WIDTH="50%" ALIGN="CENTER" VALIGN="TOP">

            <TABLE WIDTH="221" BORDER="0" CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="0">
            <TR>
                <TD><IMG SRC="gifs/tb-top-lft.jpg" ALT="Central Cottage Industries " BORDER="0" WIDTH="2" HEIGHT="2"></TD>
                <TD BACKGROUND="gifs/tb-top-bg.jpg"><IMG SRC="gifs/zero.gif" ALT="Central Cottage Industries " BORDER="0" WIDTH="1" HEIGHT="1"></TD>
                <TD><IMG SRC="gifs/tb-top-rft.jpg" ALT="Central Cottage Industries " BORDER="0" WIDTH="3" HEIGHT="2"></TD>
            </TR>
          <TR>
            <TD BACKGROUND="gifs/tb-lft-bg.jpg"><IMG SRC="gifs/zero.gif" ALT="Central Cottage Industries " BORDER="0" WIDTH="1" HEIGHT="1"></TD>
            <TD><A HREF="index.php?c_path=<?php $row['categories_id'];?>"><IMG SRC="myccic/<?=$cat_image?>" ALT="Central Cottage Industries " BORDER="0" WIDTH="216" HEIGHT="207"></A></TD>
            <TD BACKGROUND="gifs/tb-rft-bg.jpg"><IMG SRC="gifs/zero.gif" ALT="Central Cottage Industries " BORDER="0" WIDTH="1" HEIGHT="1"></TD>
          </TR>
          <TR>
            <TD><IMG SRC="gifs/tb-bottom-lft.jpg" ALT="Central Cottage Industries " BORDER="0" WIDTH="2" HEIGHT="3"></TD>
            <TD BACKGROUND="gifs/tb-bottom-bg.jpg"><IMG SRC="gifs/zero.gif" ALT="Central Cottage Industries " BORDER="0" WIDTH="1" HEIGHT="1"></TD>
            <TD><IMG SRC="gifs/tb-bottom-rft.jpg" ALT="Central Cottage Industries " BORDER="0" WIDTH="3" HEIGHT="3"></TD>
          </TR>
        </TABLE>
        <?php
        }
        else if($j==0)
        {
?>
```

Comment: You are not getting category id or category image or both ?

Comment: both  i am not getting

Comment: your fetch loop is closed AFTER after the variable assignments. that means you only ever output ONE row of data from the query. and since `$i` doesn't change inside the loop, `$j` will be 0, since `1 % 2 -> 0`.

Comment: In addition to what Marc said, you also need to `echo` your values. `<A HREF="index.php?c_path=<?php $row['categories_id'];?>">` should be `<A HREF="index.php?c_path=<?php echo $row['categories_id'];?>">`

Comment: Hello Mark, thank you for reply. but can you please show me with example.

Comment: Yess @PatrickQ, that's what i was also looking for. He did right for image but, for cat id, he missed.

Comment: I also did it but its not working for me @PatrickQ

Comment: shouldn't it be $categories_row?

Comment: Yeah, i did it too. but not working. @Wilkoklak

Comment: You have to put it into while loop anyway, so that's why it didn't work @chintan suthar

Comment: @chintansuthar There are a number of mistakes with your code, so unfortunately is it unclear exactly what it is you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Okay, but can you please help me to solve it. @Patrick Q